# How to copy the contexts of textbox into clipboard using the copy button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, textbox, copy, clipboard

I have written a code which will give some text in the textbox based on the drop-down selection.
Now I want to add a button which will copy the contents of that textbox to clipboard.
I tried many things but none of them seems to work.
I have added the button now I need some help on how to write the function for that so that I copy the contents of Textbox into the clipboard with help of single button click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  

</head> 

<script>

function myFunction() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById("Query").value;

    if(x==""){
      document.getElementById("yourquery").value = " ";
    }

    if(x=="One"){
      document.getElementById("yourquery").value = "You have choosen number :1";
    }

    if(x=="Two"){
      document.getElementById("yourquery").value = "You have choosen number :2";
    }

    if(x=="Three"){
      document.getElementById("yourquery").value = "You have choosen number : 3"
    }

    if(x=="Four"){
      document.getElementById("yourquery").value = "You have choosen number :4";
    }
}


</script>

<body>
<form>

<select id="Query" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value=''>--Select Query--</option>
        <option value='One'>One</option>
        <option value='Two'>Two</option>
        <option value='Three'>Three</option>
        <option value='Four'>Four</option>
</select>

<fieldset style="max-width:600px";"max-width:600px">
<P>Your required query is: <input type="text" id="yourquery" size="50" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></p>

<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Copy To ClipBoard" onclick="GetValue();" />

</fieldset>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy to clipboard is simple in JS use the below given approach and modify according to your needs:

```js
var copyBTN = document.querySelector('.copy');

copyBTN.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var textArea = document.querySelector('.text');
  textArea.select();
  try
  {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var result = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    alert('Copying was ' + result);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('unable to copy');
  }
});
```

```html
<p>
  <textarea class="text">Hello I'm some text</textarea>
</p>

<p>
  <button class="copy">Copy</button>
</p>
```

**UPDATE**

If you like you can use third party libraries like https://clipboardjs.com/